# programmatically create Azure AD user using C#

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am using " Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.dll " and " Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory " as reference library.

In that has IUser object  which contain " string Mail { get; set; } " property.
so if i create IUser object and assign email then email not be assign and user not created.
In AZURE Active Directory user profile has Email field.
if i create user with  DisplayName  and UserPrincipalName then it will be fine 
but with DisplayName , UserPrincipalName and Mail user not created.

```
User  Create...

protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ActiveDirectoryClient client = AuthenticationHelper.GetActiveDirectoryClientAsApplication();

    IUser newUser = new User();
    newUser.DisplayName = "New User";
    newUser.UserPrincipalName = New.User123@deoshaligram.onmicrosoft.com

    //newUser.Mail = "newuser005@gmail.com";

    client.Users.AddUserAsync(newUser).Wait(10000);
}

User not Create and Email not assign...

protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ActiveDirectoryClient client = AuthenticationHelper.GetActiveDirectoryClientAsApplication();

    IUser newUser = new User();
    newUser.DisplayName = "New User";
    newUser.UserPrincipalName = New.User123@deoshaligram.onmicrosoft.com
    newUser.Mail = "newuser005@gmail.com";

    client.Users.AddUserAsync(newUser).Wait(10000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the `otherMails` attribute on the [user object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity) rather than the `mail` attribute.

`mail` attribute is a single value field which is set by Exchange Online or On-Prem Directory Sync specifically for the SMTP address for the user.